# How to replace autogenerated firebase node id to the current user email

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to replace autogenerated firebase node id to the current user email please check code below, I'm using firebase realtime database

[image: Database Structure]

Code:

```
mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(demail, dpass)
    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                User user = new User(dname, demail, dcontact, dcity, dage);

                FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("doctors")
                        .child("Doctors_Registration")
                        .child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid())
                        .setValue(user)
                        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                
                                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                    Toast.makeText(signup.this, "Doctor Registered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                } else {
                                    Toast.makeText(signup.this, "Failed to Registered, Try Again!" + task.getException(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                }
                            }
                        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key of the node is determined by this code:

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("doctors")
        .child("Doctors_Registration")
        .child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()) // 
        .setValue(user)
```

So you're using the user's UID as the key for their node.

If you want to use the user's email you can use that instead of the UID. The only thing you'll need to take care of is to remove any `.` from the email address, as those are not a valid character in keys in the database.

So you could do:

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("doctors")
        .child("Doctors_Registration")
        .child(email.replace(".", ",")) // 
        .setValue(user)
```

Comment: Hey, @Frank van Puffelen first of all thanks for answering my question, I really appreciate that, can you please tell me why you are replacing ( . )  full stop with ( , ) comma I want to save the original user email like abc@gmail.com but after using your line of code the result is abc@gmail,com ???

Comment: I also read the above what you are saying about this. but is there is any way?   can  i use the original email of the user without containing a comma in it??